# Delaying the css animations with a preloader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, preloader

I currently have a website which uses Animate.css on the frontpage (https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). How it currently works is that the animation kicks in as soon as the user opens the website, but this causes the animation to "lag". What I would like is to let it wait until the full page loads in before the css animations start to do their thing, thus making the experience much more fluid.

I've looked into several js based preloaders, tried some but it doesn't delay the css animations. As soon as the page is finished loading, the css animations have already been completed. Am I doing something wrong, or are JS preloaders not the right approach?

Comment: I think all the 'lag' is caused by the improper css overflow: hidden-x; on the html element. It should be overflow-x: hidden;.

Comment: Sorry. I misread. I thought your site was the animate.css website. If you are already using window.onload or $(document).ready(); You could use setTimout to delay the animation a second, to give the user time to get their bearing.

Comment: @FraserCrosbie The animations are all done in pure CSS with keyframes not javascript. SetTimeout is not an option.

Comment: @magreenberg Good call. I gave your answer a vote.

Comment: Like others have said, trigger the animations on a class that gets added to the body or another contextual element and add that class via JS when you want to trigger the animations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to use javascript and/or jquery to dynamically add the css class that has the animation to the desired element after the page has been loaded. We can do this with the $document.ready event in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('css selector').addClass('class-that-has-animation-binding').
});
```

That is how he is doing it on the [main site](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) if you view is source code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to replace some of the animation with jquery, since it was too much a hassle to slide down (from off screen) a fixed element with animate.css + jquery when slideDown also does the trick. But this helped with the other animations though!

Comment: @adamk22 I find the [jquery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is super helpful when controlling animations.

Comment: @margreenberg Thank for the tip! I'll look into it!

Comment: The page will have loaded at the `$document.ready` event, but images won't have finished rendering yet, so most preloaders will still be running. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above approach didn't work for me.

Since a good preloader will wait until ALL page elements, including images, have been displayed, I would [wait until then](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/11/difference-between-jquery-document-ready-vs-Javascript-window-onload-event.html#axzz6WMbonK5a)....

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('css selector').addClass('class-that-has-animation-binding').
});
```